# How do I make btn01 or btn go to a random spot every 4 milliseconds and when you click on it it will stop and do something else?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, random

I want to make any btn go to a random spot every 3 milisecounds, and when you click the random button it will do something else like print **Hi** and stop the button from moving.
Here is the code:

I tried `while a == True:` but it keeps frezzing when i press the "To make a video" button and just frezzes for a while

```
import time
import os
import tkinter as tk
import random
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Button
import math
from tkinter import Text
from tkinter import Grid
from tkinter import Place
#from tkinter import place
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("There is no game")
window.geometry("494x300")
numberx = random.randint(1,200)
numbery = random.randint(1,200)
##def clickedrandom():
##  a = False
def toplayagame():
  print("Hi")
a = True
def tomakeavideo():
  T.delete('1.0', END)
  T.insert(tk.END, "People who are watching go hit that subscribe button and hit that like button also hit that little bell to turn on notifcations")
  T.configure(width = 25, height=6)
  while a == True:
    numberx = random.randint(1,200)
    numbery = random.randint(1,200)
    int(numberx)
    int(numbery)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    btn.place(x = numberx, y = numbery)

def pressed():
  T.delete('1.0', END)
  T.insert(tk.END, "Why are you here?")
  btn.place(x=190, y=200)
  T.configure(width = 17, height=1)
  btn.configure(text = "To play a game", width=12,command=toplayagame)
  btn1= Button(window, bd=10,text="To make a video",activebackground='White',activeforeground='Black',bg='Grey',fg='White',height=1,width=15,state=ACTIVE,command=tomakeavideo)
  btn1.pack()
  btn1.place(x=1,y=200)

T = tk.Text(window, height=1, width=10)
T.pack()
T.insert(tk.END, "Hello user")

btn = Button(window, bd=10,text="Hello",activebackground='Black',activeforeground='White',bg='Grey',fg='White',height=1,width=4,state=ACTIVE,command=pressed)
btn.pack()

btn.place(x=215, y=200)


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
"there was an error" is not a problem specification.  We need the entire error message, including trace-back, and your trace of the offending values during execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `<tkinter widget>.after(<time>, <function>)` like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import random

playing_game = False

def to_make_video():
    global btn1
    msg = "People who are watching go hit that subscribe button and"+\
          " hit that like button also hit that little bell to turn on"+\
          " notifcations"
    text_widget.delete("0.0", "end")
    text_widget.insert("end", msg)
    text_widget.configure(width=25, height=6)
    btn1.destroy()
    start_game()

def game_won():
    # When the button is pressed:
    global playing_game
    playing_game = False
    text_widget.delete("0.0", "end")
    text_widget.insert("end", "Why aren't you leaving?")
    text_widget.configure(width=23, height=1)
    btn.destroy()

def move_button():
    global playing_game
    # If the game is over stop moving the button
    if not playing_game:
        return None
    # Pick the next random position for the button
    numberx = random.randint(1, 200)
    numbery = random.randint(1, 200)
    btn.place(x=numberx, y=numbery)
    # After 500 milliseconds call `move_button` again
    # You can change the value to make it faster/slower
    root.after(500, move_button)

def start_game():
    # Start the game
    global playing_game
    btn.config(command=game_won)
    playing_game = True
    # Start the loop that keeps moving it to new random positions
    move_button()

def pressed():
    global btn1
    # Ask the user why they are here
    text_widget.delete("0.0", "end")
    text_widget.insert("end", "Why are you here?")
    text_widget.configure(width=17)

    btn.place(x=190, y=200)
    btn.configure(text="To play a game", width=12, command=lambda: None)

    btn1 = tk.Button(root, bd=10, text="To make a video", bg="grey", fg="white",
                     activebackground="white", activeforeground="black",
                     height=1, width=15, command=to_make_video)
    btn1.place(x=1, y=200)

# Create a window
root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("310x250")

text_widget = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=10)
text_widget.pack()
text_widget.insert(tk.END, "Hello user")

btn = tk.Button(root, bd=10, text="Hello", activebackground="black",
                activeforeground="white", bg="grey", fg="white", height=1,
                width=4, command=pressed)
btn.place(x=215, y=200)

# Run tkinter's mainloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But what will it look like when i add it to my code like what do i remove?

Comment: @CameronButcher when is the game supposed to start?

Comment: I want it to go Hello user then click hello, why are you here then etheir click one of the buttons but if you press (to make a video ) i want it to say hit the sub button and what all youtubers allways say then click the button that goes crazy. When you click it it says  (Why arent you leaving ) and then then the button vanishes

Comment: the game starts straight away

Comment: @CameronButcher I edited my answer. Not 100% sure that is what you wanted.